# Generate a UTF-8-pdf from a PHP website

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8

I'm trying to code a website in CakePHP where people fill in their details to apply for our university.
This is in Germany, and we have a lot of applicants, so we have names with Czech accents, German umlauts, etc.
They enter their data in a form which gets saved in a database (also in UTF-8). The site should also generate a .pdf with their name, address etc. I tried using FPDF and the unicode extension UFPDF, but somehow still fail.
Now I'm wondering if I can somehow generate a LaTeX-document and just automatically enter the user's data and compile & return it to the user. LaTeX always worked fine for me with UTF-8.

Oh, I forgot: I don't want to use TCPDF (which apparently supports UTF-8), because it already took 20secs for a Hello-World-document; I'm scared it would strangle the server when 300 students apply at the same time.

If anyone could help me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Fail as is fail-to-generate or fail-to-render? (on the off-chance it's as simple as finding a better font)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the LaTeX way, calling `exec` from PHP and creating the document.

Or you can use [TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/) which is build on FPDF but it has more functionality build in it, and it supports UTF-8.

Hm 20sec for a simple document seems very very long, I've created larger documents with many pictures (20+ pages with 3 images each page) with TCPDF and it's usually very fast, far from 20 sec even for documents of that size.

Comment: I've found tcPDF incredibly slow, even for the simplest of documents, though it isn't as big a memory-hog as some

Comment: I think TCPDF only slows down when it encounters Unicode-symbols. People have thought about that before: http://www.bitrealm.net/2010/08/tcpdf-is-slow-here-is-the-solution/ I'll try that out and report.

Comment: I have (odd enough) never had trouble with it being slow, and many of the documents I've created holds danish letters(øæå). I might have been lucky with fonts perhaps I don't know why I haven't experienced the "slowness".

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try [PDFLIB](http://www.pdflib.com/de/produkte/pdflib-familie/pdflib/)?

The company is located in your country, the product is really very professional. When we used it for a project we never had any problems with unicode support.
(I assume the direct PDF generation this way is way faster and less error-prone than executing tex).

Comment: I don't really like paying for software :)

Comment: http://www.pdflib.com/de/download/kostenlose-software/pdflib-lite-7/ take a look at the free release of the library.